# Azure File Storage ReadWriteMany access mode

Tags: azure-storage, azure-container-service

I'm pretty new on the Azure platform. Please help me to choose the most appropriate Azure components to implement the following scenario.

I have to have an HA service which will be deployed on two or more Docker containers. The access to the containers group will be done through the internal facade, like Azure Load Balancer. The most important requirement is a safe access to the File Storage, all containers have to share the same volume with an ability to read an write there simultaneously.

I read that Azure File Storage does support **ReadWriteMany** access mode.
Any thoughts what should be the best design to handle this. What I need is a direction to focus on.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Make sure to look at [AKS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/) as container orchestrator.
- Use [volume mounts](https://github.com/kubernetes/examples/blob/master/staging/volumes/azure_file/README.md) to share access to an [Azure Files share](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/azure-files-volume).
- Use [Persistent Volumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/) to abstract connection details
- Make sure to back-up your data regularly